# QML: how to show a dialog after window open?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I need to show the user a modal dialog before he or she starts working with the application. The application with dialog example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        text: "Show dialog"
        onClicked: profileDialog.open()
    }

    Dialog {
        id: profileDialog
        title: "Select profile"
        ColumnLayout {
            RadioButton {
                checked: true
                text: qsTr("First")
            }
            RadioButton {
                text: qsTr("Second")
            }
            RadioButton {
                text: qsTr("Third")
            }
        }
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok
    }

}
```

This example shows dialog on the button click. But I need to do this when the application starts. How to show profileDialog on opening main window? Maybe there is some afterShow signal? But I cannot find such signal in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In these cases the [`Component.onCompleted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) signal should be used:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    // ...
    Component.onCompleted: profileDialog.open()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have found another solution: onVisibleChanged: if (visible) profileDialog.open(). Which one is better: onVisibleChanged or Component.onCompleted?

Comment: @AndreyEpifantsev In your current case, anybody is equally valid, with my code it would only be executed in the first creation of the window, in your case every time the window is visible (for example if it hides the window and it is shown again the signal will also be triggered) , it will depend on what you want.